# Unhashable type list error when iterating through a dictionary using .items()

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary, where the keys are regular expressions, and the values are categories. My goal is to go through a column, iterate through each of the different regular expressions, and assign a new column flagged for that category. The problem I am running into is that .items() creates a list, which is an unhashable object.

```
new_columns = ['counts']
category_columns = [dictionary]

for problem_count, problem in zip(new_columns, category_columns):
    for category, reg_expr in problem.items():
        found = notes.str.contains(reg_expr, na=False) # Errors out here 
        note_data[category] = np.where(found, True, False)
    note_data[problem_count] = note_data[problem_keys()].sum(axis=1)
```

What is the best work around for this?

Comment: `items()` doesn't create a list.

Comment: It just generates the keys and values from the dictionary.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Here `for category, reg_expr in problem.items():` category is the key and reg_expr the value. In the text above you said it is the other way around.

Comment: So it should be `for reg_expr, category in problem.items():`

Comment: Post the full python traceback message and include a small sample of what your data is. `category_columns` is a list of `problems` which are dicts of regex,category pairs? And these catagories are themselves lists? Then what is `note_data[category] = ...` supposed to do? This would be more clear if we saw your input data and the exact error produced.

Answer (score 0):

If values are lists, then I would Join them with | for a regex:

```
found = notes.str.contains('|'.join(reg_expr), na=False)
```